# error classes do not show up when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate my signup form using JavaScript. I submit the form and the default action is prevented but none of my error handler classes show up, nor do I get any errors in my error log. if anyone can show me what I'm doing wrong, it would greatly appreciated. I'm trying to show a red background on the input fields if the user doesn't fill in the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#signupForm").submit(function (e) {
    removeFeedback();
    var errors = validateSignup();
    if (errors == "") {
      return true;
    } else {
      provideFeedback(errors);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false
    }
  });

  function validateSignup() {
    var errorFields = new Array();
    //Check required fields to see if they have anything in them
    if ($('#signupFirst').val() == "") {
      errorFields.push('first');
    }
    if ($('#signupLast').val() == "") {
      errorFields.push('last');
    }

    if ($('#signupEmail').val() == "") {
      errorFields.push('email');
    }

    if ($('#signupPassword').val() == "") {
      errorFields.push('pwd');
    }

    if (!($('#signupEmail').val().indexOf(".") > 2) && ($('#signupEmail').val().indexOf("@"))) {
      errorFields.push('email');
    }
    return errorFields();
  }


  function provideFeedback(errorFields) {
    for (var i = 0; i < errorFields.length; i++) {
      $("#" + errorFields[i]).addClass("inputError");
      $("#" + errorFields[i] + "Error").removeClass("errorFeedback");
    }
  }


  function removeFeedBack() {
    $('input').each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("inputError");
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="index-bg-wrapper">
    <div class="main-signup-container">
      <form id="signupForm" class="signup-form" action='include/signup.inc.php' method='POST'>
        <input id="signupFirst" type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
        <input id="signupLast" type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input id="signupEmail" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="signupPassword" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Signup</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Look in your console, there are a number of errors being thrown. `return errorFields();` should be `return errorFields;` for one thing. `errors == ""` will never evaluate to true because `errors` is an array, not a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go buddy, I have fixed multiple errors though very minor in your code but its working fine now.

Plnkr: 
http://embed.plnkr.co/MaUzZh1zUFBL4y8qAf6n/

1. You were pushing wrong name inside the errorFields array.
2. Due to wrong field name and DOM id mismatch jquery couldn't find the element and apply the class.

I hope you can compare and get this code working.

Comment: That works perfectly man. thanks much. I was seriously about to throw my laptop. I wish I could upvote this 1000. I will definatley print this out and keep it on ym my wall so I learn from. thanks again. cheers

Answer (score 2):

**This is not ok:**

```
return errorFields(); // Here you're trying to call a function with an array.
```

**Just return the array:** `return errorFields;`

**Another problem is the comparison:**

```
if (errors == "") { // This is not ok (it's always false), so, what you want to check is the length of errors.
    return true;
} else {
    provideFeedback(errors);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
}
```

**So, check for the length:**

```
if (errors.length === 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    provideFeedback(errors);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false
}
```